# Using nl2br with html tags

Tags: php, html, nl2br

I use `nl2br` when displaying some information that is saved somewhere, but when HTML tags are used I want not to add `<br>` tags for them.

For example if I use

```
<table>
<th></th>
</table>
```

it will be transformed to

```
<table><br />
<th></th><br />
</table><br />
```

and that makes a lot of spaces for this table.

Ho can break line tags be added only for other non-HTML content?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a very vague question, which amounts to "I use a function to do something to some information somewhere, but I don't want to use it under some situations." Simply don't call `nl2br` on those strings that you don't want new `<br />`s in?

Comment: Well if I don't call it, what about the other non-html tags, they need break lines.The solution is @Michiel Pater's post.Please if you don't have any solution, don't post.How can you tell me not to use it, when I need it..Please don't post anymore..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the closing tags and newlines by only closing tags:

```
$str = str_replace('>
', '>', $str);
```

Comment: Uh, literal newlines in such a context are horrible. Better use `">\n"`

Comment: heh, strange code-style :) new-line symbol can be represented by `PHP_EOL` constant or `"\n"`.

Answer (score 7):

I'd the same issue,

I made this code, adding a `<br />` at the end of each line except if the line finished with an html tag:

```
function nl2br_save_html($string)
{
    if(! preg_match("#</.*>#", $string)) // avoid looping if no tags in the string.
        return nl2br($string);

    $string = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "\n", $string);

    $lines=explode("\n", $string);
    $output='';
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $line = rtrim($line);
        if(! preg_match("#</?[^/<>]*>$#", $line)) // See if the line finished with has an html opening or closing tag
            $line .= '<br />';
        $output .= $line . "\n";
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is wrong. If you are typing

```
<table>
<th></th>
</table>
```

into a text area then no matter what you do It will include `<br />` in between them. Because it is what `nl2br` is supposed to do.