# wordpress mail header set else plain text

Tags: php, wordpress, function, mime

Hope to get some help with a piece of code, I am using a theme for wordpress which sets the mail headers to text/html, this causes some problems with plain text mail ex. linebreaks don't show anymore.

I tried setting :

```
} else {
    return 'text/plain';
}
```

but I don't know php very well so I don't know where to place it to make it work. I would like to set the text/plain for mails not defined.

this is the code for the wp header :

```
 /**
 * filter mail headers
 */
function wp_mail($compact) {
    if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'lostpassword') return $compact;
    if ($compact['headers'] == '') {

        //$compact['headers']   = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $compact['headers'] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        $compact['headers'].= "From: " . get_option('blogname') . " < " . get_option('admin_email') . "> \r\n";
    }

    $compact['message'] = str_ireplace('[site_url]', home_url() , $compact['message']);
    $compact['message'] = str_ireplace('[blogname]', get_bloginfo('name') , $compact['message']);
    $compact['message'] = str_ireplace('[admin_email]', get_option('admin_email') , $compact['message']);

    $compact['message'] = html_entity_decode($compact['message'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $compact['subject'] = html_entity_decode($compact['subject'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

    //$compact['message']       =   et_get_mail_header().$compact['message'].et_get_mail_footer();

    return $compact;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing that, change your plain line breaks to html.

```
$message=nl2br($message); // of course use your var name.
```

That way you get to keep a standard format for email as well. plain text has nothing so special to need a separate header in this case. This function will convert all line breaks to html version.

Other than new lines most of your plain text will hold its formatting even in html because it has no special tags.

Here is how you will place it

```
function wp_mail($compact) {
    // leave your existing code intact here, don't remove it.
    $compact["message"]=nl2br($compact["message"]); 
    return $compact;
}
```

Comment: Hi Hanky 웃 Panky,your answer makes so much sense, I feel I'm almost there. based on the code I posted above , is it possible to know what the var should be ? and where would I place the line of code you posted ?

Comment: Yes your variable is `$compact["message"]=nl2br($compact["message"]);` and it goes right above the last line of your function. I.e. Above the return call. See the edit

Comment: I've tried what suggested and it works for plain text emails ,they now have a correct line break but now html emails are shown as blank. I looked at the source and I see that every line is getting the <br> tag  `code <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><br /> <html><br /> <head><br /> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/><br /> <style type="text/css"><br />`

Comment: Ok then move the call up to become thr first line of your function

Comment: I moved it up just below of `function wp_mail` but still every line has a <br /> tag. I found this other topic which I believe strip the tag if html, not sure how to use it. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108088/using-nl2br-with-html-tags)

Comment: Then the function which is calling this function is sending the email body including all the html tags. You just take this call there and look for a point where the actual email text is fetched only and header and footer are not attached to it yet. That is where this should go.

Comment: I've found the file which has all the mail functions but it a little overwhelming, I tried placing the code at some places where I see the header being defined but no luck yet.  ex `public static function header_email() {
        $blog_name = get_option('blogname');
        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        $headers.= "From: " . $blog_name . " < " . get_option('admin_email') . "> \r\n";
        $headers = apply_filters('filter_header_email_', $headers);
        return $headers;
    }` thanks for your help,

Comment: I'm sure if I could share the file someone would see where to place it.